# Echo Telephone number on OpenCart footer

Tags: php, opencart

Is it possible to `echo` telephone number on OpenCart `footer.tpl`?

I used `<?php echo $telephone; ?>` on my footer, but it is showing error `Notice: Undefined index...`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, open `

catalog/controller/common/footer.php`

```
 $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');          $data['text_newsletter'] = $this->language->get('text_newsletter');
```

`<?php echo $telephone; ?>` on `footer.tpl`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly show in tpl using:

```
echo    $this->config->get('config_telephone');
```